# Unable to Preview Expo React Native in IOS/Android

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

Unable to resolve module ./_getAllKeys from D:\Github\IT Fundamental\itlearning\Bootcamp\10\front-end_akhir\node_modules\lodash_equalObjects.js:

None of these files exist:

- node_modules\lodash_getAllKeys(.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.css|.native.css|.css)
- node_modules\lodash_getAllKeys\index(.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.css|.native.css|.css)

> 1 | var getAllKeys = require('./_getAllKeys');
> |                           ^
> 2 |
> 3 | /** Used to compose bitmasks for value comparisons. */
> 4 | var COMPARE_PARTIAL_FLAG = 1;

RCTFatal
RCTConvertArrayValue
C49A5FC2-C873-3913-9603-004F5D0175E7
C49A5FC2-C873-3913-9603-004F5D0175E7
C49A5FC2-C873-3913-9603-004F5D0175E7
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
5A6C1F41-BF70-32F6-A1D6-5B894DD21362
5A6C1F41-BF70-32F6-A1D6-5B894DD21362
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
6398DDD4-EA36-31CD-B849-2F6217205BED
UIApplicationMain
main
28D6D2C1-46CE-3D58-B744-B06A6C573888

I just wanna to load preview in IOS/Android using Expo, but end up only able to load in Web